# Xuggle API - Output video file size increasing.

Tags: xuggler, xuggle

I am trying to run a basic scenario using Xuggle API, where I am giving an input FLV file and writing it into another FLV file.

I used the same input parameters (e.g. Bit rate, Width and Height); however, after conversion, I am getting much bigger output video file 2-3 times of input video size.

Please see below FFMPEG command output of both the videos.

Input video:

```
anilj@desk1:~/workspace/androws/XuggleMedia$ ffmpeg -i input/internetCrashing.flv
ffmpeg version N-36083-g2501f93-xuggle-5.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  3 2014 13:43:04 with gcc 4.6.4
  configuration: --prefix=/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome --extra-version=xuggle-5.5 --extra-cflags=-I/home/anilj/workspace/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/stage/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/anilj/workspace/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/stage/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome/lib --disable-shared --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx
Input #0, flv, from 'input/internetCrashing.flv':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 344
    totaldatarate   : 299
    bytelength      : 12850666
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : B4A7DD5A3MM1402426875642882
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
  Duration: 00:05:43.97, start: 0.000000, **bitrate: 298 kb/s**
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 400x226, 263 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 56 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Output video:

```
anilj@desk1:~/workspace/androws/XuggleMedia$ ffmpeg -i output/output1.flv
ffmpeg version N-36083-g2501f93-xuggle-5.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  3 2014 13:43:04 with gcc 4.6.4
  configuration: --prefix=/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome --extra-version=xuggle-5.5 --extra-cflags=-I/home/anilj/workspace/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/stage/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/anilj/workspace/xuggle-xuggler/build/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/captive/stage/home/anilj/workspace/xugglehome/lib --disable-shared --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-version3 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx
Input #0, flv, from 'output/output1.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.3.100
  Duration: 00:05:44.05, start: 0.000000, **bitrate: 935 kb/s**
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 226x400, 200 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, stereo, s16, 64 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
anilj@desk1:~/workspace/androws/XuggleMedia$
```

I see that there is a huge difference between the bit rate (shown in BOLD). I could not understand how did this bit rate change so much and where do I control it from Xuggle APIs.

I am using below code to do the processing. Note that I am using the same input parameters of video.

```
public void onAddStream(IAddStreamEvent event) {
        int streamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
        IStreamCoder streamCoder = event.getSource().getContainer()
                .getStream(streamIndex).getStreamCoder();
        if (streamCoder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            streamCoder.setBitRate((int) audioBitRate);
            writer.addAudioStream(streamIndex, streamIndex, audioChannelCount, audioSampleRate);
        } else if (streamCoder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            streamCoder.setWidth(VIDEO_WIDTH);
            streamCoder.setHeight(VIDEO_HEIGHT);
            streamCoder.setBitRate((int) videoBitRate);
            writer.addVideoStream(streamIndex, streamIndex, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        }
        super.onAddStream(event);
    }

    public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
        IVideoPicture pic = event.getPicture();
        if (videoResampler == null) {
            videoResampler = IVideoResampler.make(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT,
                    pic.getPixelType(), pic.getWidth(),
                    pic.getHeight(), pic.getPixelType());
        }
        IVideoPicture out = IVideoPicture.make(pic.getPixelType(), VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        videoResampler.resample(out, pic);

        IVideoPictureEvent asc = new VideoPictureEvent(event.getSource(), out, event.getStreamIndex());
        super.onVideoPicture(asc);
        out.delete();
    }

    public void onAudioSamples(IAudioSamplesEvent event) {
        IAudioSamples samples = event.getAudioSamples();
        if (audioResampler == null) {
            audioResampler = IAudioResampler.make(audioOutputChannels, samples.getChannels(), audioOutputRate, samples.getSampleRate());
        }
        if (event.getAudioSamples().getNumSamples() > 0) {
            IAudioSamples out = IAudioSamples.make(samples.getNumSamples(), samples.getChannels());
            audioResampler.resample(out, samples, samples.getNumSamples());

            AudioSamplesEvent asc = new AudioSamplesEvent(event.getSource(), out, event.getStreamIndex());
            super.onAudioSamples(asc);
            out.delete();
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something here, which is causing problem?